# Example of SimpleModal with ASP.NET webforms project

Tags: asp.net, simplemodal, webforms

I'm looking for a example or article that demonstrates using SimpleModal in an ASP.NET webforms project.

Ideally the article would show creates and edits of a grid row using simplemodal.

Comment: Are you talking about the SimpleModal jQuery plugin?

Comment: Sorry, yes I mean the SimpleModal jQuery plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

http://beckelman.net/post/2008/09/11/Modal-Delete-Confirmation-in-an-ASPNET-ListView-Using-SimpleModal-jQuery-Plugin.aspx

It's a little old, but the concepts should still apply. You'll want to make sure to use the appendTo option in SimpleModal:

```
$(el).modal({appendTo: 'form'});
```

-Eric

Answer (score 1):

The developer's page is pretty nice and gives a good example of how to use it: [SimplModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)

There is also an old stackoverflow question that may help: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29174/simplemodal-breaks-asp-net-postbacks)

This may also help: [SimpleModal issues](http://blog.hurlman.com/post/jQuery2c-simpleModal2c-and-ASPNet-postbacks-do-not-play-well-together.aspx)