# ASP Button OnClick codebehind has no action

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, onclick, code-behind

I am completely dumbfounded by this. I have created many webforms and been successful with the same approach. I have seen many posts on this exchange regarding similar issues, but i haven't seen anything completely pertinent.

When I click on the Button, nothing occurs.

Does anyone know what I have missed?

My HTML and ASP markup are as follows:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn_AddSystem" onclick="BtnClick_SubmitNewSystem" Text="Add" />
```

The C# codebehind:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        btn_AddSystem.Click += new EventHandler(this.BtnClick_SubmitNewSystem);
   }

    protected void BtnClick_SubmitNewSystem(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("working");
        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If nothing means that it not even post to server then It might be possible that you have some validators in place causing this.

Comment: Try to disable ValidationControls  or put "CauseValidation=false" at your button markup

Comment: I have added the CauseValidation to false, still no action.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Based on further investigation. My buttons are with a SimpleModal jQuery plugin which was effectively moving the buttons outside of the ASP code.

[SimpleModal breaks ASP.Net Postbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29174/simplemodal-breaks-asp-net-postbacks)

I am happy for this post to be marked for deletion.

Comment: I am using jQuery Dialog and could not figure out why my OnClick code behind code was not firing... ty